# Making path and path elements unambiguous

Tags: antlr4

In my text files I can have both path elements (like `a`) and paths (like `a.b.c`). The fact that path and path element can be ambiguous is giving me headaches.

If I have lexer elements like this

```
PATH : PATH_ELEMENT('.'PATH_ELEMENT)* ;
PATH_ELEMENT : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
```

and I have source text

```
dir : a
path1 : a.b.c
path2 : a
```

If I use PATH for both then it will work, but it will not flag an error if `dir` has a segmented path.

If I swap the order of the lexer items and use `PATH_ELEMENT` for `dir` and `PATH` for `pathX` then the first two will work OK but then `path2` will match `PATH_ELEMENT` when it is expecting `PATH`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why is it a problem for you to get `PATH` as result for `dir`? You could check if it contains more than a single element by examining the size  of the `PATH_ELEMENT()` member in you `PATHContext` instance.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's a problem, but it seems inelegant. I'll probably end up with a lot of fairly generic 'identifier' tokens in the style of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`, and it will be a pain to always use `PATH` and then have to disambiguate later.